# How to write negative currency in text?

Tags: grammaticality, numbers

Which version is grammatically correct (given that I hopefully provided at least one correct alternative)?

> [...] the company yielded a result to the amount of **−€6.680** billion in 2008.

or

> [...] the company yielded a result to the amount of **€−6.680** billion in 2008.

Since I'm not a native speaker, I'd appreciate any other tips/corrections as well.

Comment: We don't use signs in these kind of contexts. I'd simply say *the company had a loss of 6.6 billion.*, etc.

Comment: Ok thanks. What if I wanted to write that the NIAT (net income after taxes) was ... [insert one of the above]? What would then be the right one? :)

Comment: I would still avoid using the currency sign. I’d write, “The company’s NIAT was –2.84 million euro”, typing out the name of the currency instead of using the € sign.

Comment: Thanks  for your comments so far. So how come in these two texts (arbitrary google results after a 2 minute search) both use only text-currencies and symbol-currencies? http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-08-31/dollar-climbs-on-taper-bets-amid-syria-tension-rupee-tumbles.html and http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-08-31/pound-strengthens-versus-euro-on-boe-rate-bets-gilts-decline.html I'd say the text-variant is clearly the right/common one, but there are phrases which say: [...] to $123. Would that be an inconsistency then? I just want to understand it better.

Comment: Actually, **in text,** if the net income after tax is a loss, say that. "The company made a net loss after tax of €2.84m"

Comment: I'm confused. Because @AndrewLeach seems to be right as well: http://www.economist.com/news/business/21584354-steve-ballmer-casualty-personal-computers-rapid-decline-defenestrated?fsrc=rss|bus

Comment: There is no definitive answer as to whether a currency symbol ($) or a currency name ([US] dollars) should be used. That depends on whether you are naming a one-off amount in a textual context or have lots of amounts mentioned in close proximity.

Comment: I see. Then I'll stick the symbol since there are quite a few amounts mentioned.

Comment: @Noah Oh yes, everyone does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, you would not write out the minus sign in descriptive text.

> The company suffered losses in excess of $7 billion.
>
> The company suffered a 2.4 million dollar deficit.

The words "losses" and "deficit" make the minus sign redundant and unnecessary.

The only example I can think of where you might need to be explicit would be a table, where you might be showing both losses and profits.  In that case you would probably use the (loss) syntax common in financial docs:

> Company X:   $2.1M
>
> Company Y:  ($1.4M)

Though you could conceivably use a minus sign as well and your point would be made clear:

> Company X:   $2.1M
>
> Company Y:  -$1.4M

Comment: +1, except that you have both "$" and "dollar" in *$2.4 million dollar*.

Comment: More than just being redundant and unnecessary, I’d say a minus sign when dealing with losses actually _change the meaning_. A net loss of –2.4 million dollars is a net _gain_ of 2.4 million dollars.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Good point, I edited my op. Lynn, thanks.

Comment: Note that in some cultures, the accounting negative sign is properly placed **after** the amount rather than before, as in $2.1M-. Also note that M often indicates thousands rather than millions, with in that case MM indicating millions. Also, billion should **never** be used without a comment as to whether it refers to a European billion (10^12) or an American billion (10^9).

Comment: Minor style note: Avoid using a hyphen for a minus sign when possible. If a proper minus sign isn't available, it's generally acceptable to use a figure dash or en dash instead. They generally have the same appearance as a minus sign (the most important thing being width) whereas a hyphen does not.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I can't speak for the rest of Europe, but would say that, in British English, altho' *billion* used to mean 10^12, we have now almost exclusively adopted the Am usage of 10^9.

Comment: @TrevorD Oh... damnit. I should have specified that, that would have been very helpful from the beginning: I adopted the, um, styles and spelling versions of American English for this project.

Answer (score 6):

The minus sign is always the *leftmost*: **-**(rest of the symbols).

The currency symbol is always *adjacent* to the figure: **€**(amount).

To avoid ambiguity and help readability, one may place the minus sign in parentheses:
**(-) €6.680**

Comment: Thanks. I always like to add a minor space, [generated by `\,` in LaTeX, between symbols and figures (unrelated to which side the symbol is on)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74354/25683). It's maybe wrong but I prefer this typographical quirk ever since I picked up on it in some LaTeX-related discussion.

Comment: Never ever have I seen (-) €123, and if I had I wouldn't have known what to make of it. Is it an optional character like in "a(n)"? Why is there spacing between, does it apply to the previous word maybe? Is it ascii art? If I'd not be on this page I'd have no idea what this means. Definitely don't use that to avoid "ambiguity and help readability", moving the symbol further away from what it applies to and introducing symbols that carry additional but unintended meaning would not achieve either goal. Maybe it's conventional in field XYZ but it's neither less ambiguous nor more readable.